# How can i return the second element in the list that starts with "b"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function with lists that has strings in it and I have to find the second element in this list that starts with "b".

for example:

```
second_elemnt_starting_with_b(["b", "a", "bb"]) => "bb"
```

Comment: What is the expected output if none start with b?

Answer (score 7):

It would be more efficient to use a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), rather than build lists of all strings starting with 'b' by iterating over the whole initial list, then only keep the second one.

```
def second_element_starting_with_b(lst):
    # g is a generator, it will produce items lazily when we call 'next' on it 
    g = (item for item in lst if item.startswith('b'))
    next(g)  # skip the first one
    return next(g)



second_element_starting_with_b(["b", "a", "bb"]) 
# 'bb'
```

This way, the code stops iterating on the initial list as soon as the string we are looking for is found.

As suggested by @Chris_Rands, it is also possible to avoid repeated calls to next by using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). This way, an extended version looking for the nth item starting with 'b' would look like:

```
from itertools import islice

def nth_element_starting_with_b(lst, n):
    "Return nth item of lst starting with 'b', n=1 for first item"
    g = (item for item in lst if item.startswith('b'))
    return next(islice(g, n-1, n))



nth_element_starting_with_b(["b", "a", "bb"], 2) 
# 'bb'
```

Comment: more general `next(itertools.islice(g, 1, 2))`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but could you further explain what does "item for item" excatly do in this code?

Comment: @felexeriino: This is a generator expression, as described in [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). The syntax is similar to the one for list comprehensions (with parentheses instead of square brackets), but no list is built, the values are generated one by one on the fly when one iterates over the generator.

Comment: @Chris_Rands That's a good idea, I added an extended version using it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
def  second_elemnt_starting_with_b(list_):
    return [i for i in list_ if i.startswith('b')][1]

print(second_elemnt_starting_with_b(["b", "a", "bb"]))
```

**Output** :

```
'bb'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ["b", "a", "bb"]

print([i for i in lst if i.startswith("b")][1])
```

Output:

```
"bb"
```

Or as a function:

```
def func(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if i.startswith("b")][1]
```

Comment: Yeah, it works but not if u have a function and the list as a parameter: for example if i have: def get_2nd_elemnt_starting_with_b(list) it needs to return the String, with the second elemnt starting with "b"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python built-in function **startswith()** to check the first element of the string.

```
lst = ["b", "a", "bb"]

# Check the first element
sample = "Sample"
print(sample.startswith("S"))
# Output : True
```

Now, you need to iterate through list to check each of the indices that starts with **b**

```
# Create empty list
lst_2 = []
# Loop through list
for element in lst.startswith("b"):
    # Add every element starts with b
    lst_2.append(element)
    # Print the second element which starts with b
    print(lst_2[1])
```